# WAITING TTFB is too much on live

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I am using nodejs with HTML and jQuery. I am sending multiple requests on page load

each request is taking too much time . Also, i noticed request is queued at 7.67. how we can stop that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Time to first byte (TTFB) measures the duration from the user or client making an HTTP request to the first byte of the page being received by the client's browser.

In most cases, on sending an AJAX request, you will complete these steps:

1. Frontend: open a socket
2. Frontend: send the request to server
3. Backend: parse the request
4. Backend: process data (query on database, post-process,...)
5. Backend: send response data back to frontend
6. Close the socket

TTFB is the time between step 1 and 5. There are 2 factors that can affect TTFB:

- Ping time between frontend and backend (network, route, DNS,...)
- Logic on the backend (database query takes too much of time,...)

And for long "Queued at" time:

> The most common issue seen is a series of items that are queued or stalled. This indicates that too many resources are being retrieved from a single domain. On HTTP 1.0/1.1 connections, Chrome enforces a maximum of six TCP connections per host. If you are requesting twelve items at once, the first six will begin and the last half will be queued. Once one of the original half is finished, the first item in the queue will begin its request process.

For reducing this delay, you should reduce the number of requests sent by frontend at a given time. HTTP/2 or HTTP/3 may also help.

Comment: my requirement is i have to send 100 ajax request at a time. each request is doing their stuff differently. how to do it then

Comment: It depends on your structure. Just imagine you need to buy 100 fruits from a store. Now what you're doing is asking the store to deliver fruit A, then wait until the fruit is delivered, then request fruit B,...

What can you improve?

Comment: no, i want all fruits to be deliver on same time . so no idea how to handle